# How to prepend a zero vector to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` variable `X` which has a `shape` of `(14931, 381)`.

That's 14,931 examples, with each example having 381 features. I want to add 483 features (each with a zero) value to each example, except I want them to be before the 381 existing ones

How can this be done?

Comment: Build a new dataframe with same index as the original dataframe and 14,931 rows of 483 values of `0`. Concat the new dataframe before the original one with `axis=1` to have a column concatenation. Assign it to the original dataframe variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demonstration purpose let's set up a smaller DataFrame
(7 rows and 2 columns, with feature (column) names `f1`, `f2`, ...):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'f1': [ 1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 2, 3 ],
    'f2': [ 4, 6, 5, 0, 2, 3, 2 ]})
```

Then, let's create a DataFrame filled with zeroes, to be
prepended to *df* (3 columns instead of your 483):

```
zz = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((df.shape[0], 3), dtype=int),
    columns=[ 'p' + str(n + 1) for n in range(3) ], index=df.index)
```

As you can see:

- I named the "new" columns as `p1`, `p2` and so on,
- the index is a copy of the index in *df* (it will be important
  at the next stage).

And the last step is to join these 2 DataFrames and substitute under
*df*:

```
df = zz.join(df)
```

The last step for you is to change the number of added columns to the
proper value.

Comment: What does the `index=df.index` do?

Comment: For proper execution of *join*, both Dataframes should have "corresponding" indices. Because I was not sure about the content of index in *df*, I created *zz* with just **the same** index (copied from *df*).

Answer (score 3):

Create a DataFrame of zeros and call `pd.concat`.

```
v = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=range(483))
df = pd.concat([v, df], axis=1)
```